# How would I save data in a YAML file in Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I’m currently creating a discord.py bot, which is in Python and I
needed to in some way save data. I tried looking at many types of databases, but there were a little too hard for me at the moment, so I wanted to make it simply read and write.
I want it to save like this, more of just simply writing and reading.

I couldn’t find any documentations or anything on google.

```
channelSug:

- SERVER_ID_HERE: CHANNEL_ID_HERE
```

Comment: did you check some documentation about yaml files? Like for example this one: https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-parse-and-extract-data-from-a-yaml-file-in-python

Comment: PyYAML library might be a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read/write YAML, you'll need the `PyYAML` library installed, so do that with `pip install PyYAML`.

Then you could write a dict wrapper like

```
import os
import yaml

class YAMLPersistedDict:
    def __init__(self, *, filename):
        self.data = {}
        self.filename = filename
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.filename):
            with open(self.filename, "r") as fp:
                self.data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
   
    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as fp:
            yaml.dump(self.data, fp)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        # Pass through to dict
        return getattr(self.data, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<{self.filename!r}: {repr(self.data)}>'


d = YAMLPersistedDict(filename="./config.yaml")
d["servers"] = ["foo", "bar"]
d.save()

d = YAMLPersistedDict(filename="./config.yaml")
print(d)
```

Do note you'd need to call `d.save()` after every modification, and concurrent saves (especially since you're talking async Discord stuff) could break things.